# How to align 3 divs side by side, with 1 to left, 1 to center and 1 to the right?

Tags: html, css

It would be a navigation bar, top of the page, fixed.
Part of the HTML code related to this:

```
<nav>
                <div id="chameleon"><a href="#"><img src="img/chameleon.png"></a></div>
                <div id="menulogo">
                    <center><img src="img/champic_text.png" size="80%"; align="middle"></center>
                </div>
                <div id="menustripes" onclick="showmenu()"><a href="#"><img src="img/menu.png"></a></div>
</nav>
```

So I want to align left the chameleon div, center the menulogo div and align right the menustripes div.
I've tried a lot of solutions, but I couldn't align mathematically center the menulogo div :(

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Move the #menulogo div to be the last div in the nav, float the #chameleon left, #menustripes right, and set the text-align of the nav to center:

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
}
#menustripes {
  float: right;
}
#chameleon {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="chameleon">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/chameleon.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="menustripes" onclick="showmenu()">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/menu.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="menulogo">
    <img src="img/champic_text.png" size="80%" ; align="middle">
  </div>
</nav>
```

Or keep the elements in the existing order and use flexbox:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="chameleon">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/chameleon.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="menulogo">
    <img src="img/champic_text.png" size="80%" ; align="middle">
  </div>
  <div id="menustripes" onclick="showmenu()">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/menu.png">
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is 2 more ways (works on older browsers), though I recommend *j08691*'s `flex` version

Using `display: table`

```css
nav {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
nav > * {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
}
nav > *:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: left;
}
nav > *:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="chameleon">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/chameleon.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="menustripes" onclick="showmenu()">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/menu.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="menulogo">
    <img src="img/champic_text.png" size="80%" align="middle">
  </div>
</nav>
```

Using `display: inline-block`

```css
nav > * {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}
nav > *:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: left;
}
nav > *:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="chameleon">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/chameleon.png"></a>
  </div><!--
  --><div id="menustripes" onclick="showmenu()">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/menu.png"></a>
  </div><!--
  --><div id="menulogo">
    <img src="img/champic_text.png" size="80%" ; align="middle">
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding following class might help

```
.grid {
display: inline-block;
width: 30%;     <-- Change accordingly
margin: 0;
padding: 3.33%;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
You can make three different class/id for all three divs
```

Comment: it aligns three divs equally; just changing width and padding will give the desired result